# Binding in UIViewRepresentableView breaks ObservableObject functionality

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having an UIViewRepresentableView that creates a MKMapView for me. I'm using two ObservedObjects for handling pins that the user can drop and for keeping track of the current location. Everything works fine so far. However, if if additionally insert a Binding to my ContentView's State (the one that holds the map view), the changes on the ObservableObjects' @Published properties don't cause the map view to refresh anymore. I really don't understand why this is ...

My ContentView that holds the UIViewRepresentable MapView

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var showPhotos = false
@ObservedObject var regionManager: LocationManager
@ObservedObject var annotationManager: AnnotationManager

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            MyMap(showPhotos: $showPhotos, locationManager: regionManager, annotationManager: annotationManager)
            Button(action: {
                self.regionManager.goToUserLocation()
            }) {
                LocationButton()
            }
        }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .navigationBarTitle("Long-press to select location", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

}

My actual MapView

```
struct MyMap: UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var showPhotos: Bool

@ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager
@ObservedObject var annotationManager: AnnotationManager

func makeCoordinator() -> MyMap.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {

    let map = MKMapView()
    map.delegate = context.coordinator
    context.coordinator.map = map

    locationManager.configureUserLocation()
    map.showsUserLocation = true

    map.setRegion(locationManager.currentRegion, animated: true)

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.didLongPress(gesture:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    map.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

    return map
}

func updateUIView(_ map: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    if annotationManager.currentAnnotation != nil {
        map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)
        map.addAnnotation(annotationManager.currentAnnotation!)
    }

    map.setRegion(locationManager.currentRegion, animated: true)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var parent: MyMap
    var map: MKMapView?

    init(_ parent: MyMap) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        parent.showPhotos = true
    }

    @objc func didLongPress(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //...
    }


}
```

}